# Facing Lost Updates while trying to Horizontally Scale a Spring Boot APP connected to Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The Architecture I am working on today consists of 2 instances of the same springboot app connected to a single datasource i.e PostgreSQL Database.

For all database queries I rely heavily on Spring Data JPA. I use the JpaRepository Interface to perform actions like findById , save etc.

The Spring Boot application mostly behaves like an Events ingestor, whose primary task is to take in requests and make updates in the database.

The Load balancer directs requests alternatively two each application server.
It is highly likely that 2 or more incoming concurrent requests need to access the same row/entity in the Database.

Today, even though we say repository.saveAndFlush(), we observe that the final save happened with a stale entity i.e some columns are not updated with the info from previous incoming requests.

Can someone point me in the right direction with the best design and spring data features to avoid such inconsistent states in the DB ?

Comment: You will want to learn about transactions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html. Also here you can read how Spring works with transactions: https://www.baeldung.com/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring. But make sure you first understand how transactions work in the database itself before jumping into how Spring works with transactions.

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel Thank you for your response. I missed out to say that I am doing the block of updates within a \\@Transactional method. The question is since there are two app servers, both servers select the same row for update. Now when one transaction commits before the other, isnt only the latest transaction recorded ? Kind of like a lost update problem ?

Comment: The default level of @Transactional is READ_COMMITTED, so in other words, non-repeatable read and phantom reads are still possible at that level, one of which you're suffering from (if I understand the problem correctly then you're suffering from non-repeatable reads but it could also be phantom reads, would need more detail to say for sure). Here you can get a good primer of the different isolation levels and the problems that each level of isolation solves: https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/

Comment: @JonckvanderKogel Thanks again. The above resources made a lot of sense. As you have rightly said, I am suffering from the non-repeatable read. I was not able to understand how \@Transactional(isolation=REPEATABLE_READ) works. If there are two concurrent transactions operating on the same row, what exactly happens ? Is the row locked ? or is another select statement issued during commit for comparison and assurance that it is a repeatable read ?

Comment: It's a big topic but definitely worth it to understand well how the database manages the different levels of isolation. Here is a good description of what the database does at which isolation level: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html